# Checking Promise or Callback type of an API

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How can we test the type of an API?
It is not practical to check Chrome version for each API.

For example `chrome.contextMenus.removeAll()` is still callback (but may change in future).

```js
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(() => chrome.contextMenus.create(item));

// ----- vs -----

chrome.contextMenus.removeAll()
.then (() => chrome.contextMenus.create(item));
```

Using `then()` on an API that hasn't been converted to a Promise will result in error.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

Using a callback on an API that has been converted to a Promise will also result in error.

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
```

Previously: [List of Promise API in manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843310/list-of-promise-api-in-manifest-v3)

Answer (score 0):

I consulted with one of our engineers. The short answer is that you don't need to. If you pass a callback, no promise will be returned, and you'll get a promise if you don't pass a callback.

This should be true of all methods that take callbacks. If you know of one or find one where this isn't true, please let me know in a comment and I'll look into it.

Comment: The point is that we dont know which API has been converted to Promise, therefore passing `.then()` to an API that hasn't been converted to a promise results in error.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I have come up with so far has been the following:

```js
// result for a callback type API
typeof chrome.contextMenus.removeAll()?.then()              // 'undefined'

// result for a Promise type API
typeof chrome.storage.local.get()?.then()                   // 'object'
```

Therfore, the type can be checked like the following:

```js
typeof browser.contextMenus.removeAll()?.then() === 'undefined' ?
      chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(() => someFuntion()) :
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll().then(() => someFuntion());
```